# Error compile in "Use Facebook Login example"

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk, sample

I'm trying to create the Login Application in [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) tutorial:

I'm getting this error in my logcat:

```
11-22 15:57:53.863: E/AndroidRuntime(816): com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot use SessionLoginBehavior SSO_WITH_FALLBACK when com.facebook.LoginActivity is not declared as an activity in AndroidManifest.xml
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Show us some code, it's difficult to tell it just by the error message.

Comment: I have my login button as my main activity, and I was going to make it disappear after login. Does Login HAVE to be it's own activity?

Answer (score 76):

May you forgot to define `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_facebook_login" >
</activity>
```

Comment: as this might not be the launcher activity then what can we do in this case?

Comment: I am assuming that this is an activity that exists in the Facebook SDK that will included in my apk file. Or, is it a reference to an activity in the Facebook app required to already be installed on the device?

Answer (score 64):

I had the same problem and it was because I forgot to add the **com.facebook.LoginActivity** activity to *AndroidManifest.xml*.

Also check that you followed the steps on the "*Create a new Android Project with Facebook Login*" section on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ , specially those regarding adding the *app_id* string to *res/values/strings.xml*, the *INTERNET* permission, the *com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId* Meta Data, and finally the mentioned LoginActivity.

Comment: Ya that works ... added this :::  <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >

Answer (score 12):

While the original question is related to SDK 3.0 I think it's worth mentioning that in SDK v4.0.+ the activity that needs to be declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` is `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` eg:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 3):

In this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:label="title_facebook_login" >
</activity>
```

is not mentioned.

Add this in `AndroidMainfest.xml` and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/LoginActivity/

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```